# help to convert java code to C#

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages

i was trying to get the C# version of the following java code snippet,

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1024-");
```

this is what i have so far

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(someUri);
 request.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=1024-");
```

but it is not working,what is the right way for me go?

Comment: the java code works fine,but not the C# code

Comment: But he's asking what's **not** working.

Comment: _What_ with the C# code isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your URI is HTTP since Java's `HttpURLConnection` is designed for a HTTP connection. WebRequest is abstract and can handle multiple protocols. However, by specifiying a `HttpWebRequest` type, you can access HTTP-specific methods.
The `Range` header is [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx) and you should use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.addrange.aspx) to set the property instead of directly adding it to the `Header` collection.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(someUri);
request.AddRange("bytes",1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting two different things.

A [request property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) is a value passed to the page.

A [header property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.headers.aspx) is a header in the HTTP request. Something like setting the HTTP REFERER (sic).